# Can multiple people share the same shelve set in TFS?

Tags: tfs, version-control, shelve, tfvc

I am looking for an alternative to branching in TFS with the goal of allowing multiple developers to continually integrate into a single changeset that is not in branch (aka a shelveset).

I know that a single user can update their own shelveset, and other users can pull that shelveset - but is it possible to allow several users to modify the same shelveset?

I understand that branching is preferred but I would still like to know if it is possible, maybe by using some sort of TFS powertool or modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. A shelveset is owned by a single user. it's also not recommended, as the shelveset is only a single snapshot of the change.

If you'd like something like this, you could consider `git tf` to create a local git repository which can be synced between two developers. Once they're finished one of the developers can push the change(s) back into TFS.

Moving from TFVC to Git has become easier with the release of TFS 2015u1:

> ### Team Services | TFS 2015
>
> In Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1, a project administrator can add a Git repo to a team project created with Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). You can also add a TFVC repo to a team project created with Git. This allows you to adopt a new version control system while preserving all the data in your team project.

As to ways to persuade people to move, that's a hard question. You'd first need to understand what is holding them back, explain the, what advantages Git brings, what disadvantages you see in the current setup. You will probably need to hand-hold or train them so they get comfortable with Git. Using git-tf for a while may give them more confidence to make the move.

Comment: ooooh git tf; I like the sound of that :) thank you I will give it a try.

Comment: With TFS 2015 and later, you could make a full move to Git and get away from TFVC if you want. Same with Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: @jessehouwing You mean TFS 2013.

Comment: Well, yes and no... With TFS 2013 it was easy to start with Git. With 2015 and the ability to add a new repo under the same team project it has become easy to move.

Comment: @jessehouwing I want to make the move to GIT, and half of the org is ready but there is still resistance. I think fear is the motivating factor in keeping TFS - how can I persuade them?

Comment: PS are you say we can create a GIT repo along side of our TFS repo? Does this just require VS2015 or TFS2015?

Comment: TFS 2015u1+ or TFS 2017 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/team-projects